# chkdsk information on failing SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod, chkdsk

I have a Windows 10 PC which recently started having random BSODs with a different error code each time (process crashed, invalid store, and more). After narrowing down the problem to the SSD by swapping it to a known-working PC, I ran `chkdsk` on the drive after booting from a Windows Recovery USB. This is the result of that:

```
X:\Sources> chkdsk C: /r /x /v
The type of the file system is is NTFS.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  <left out; succeeded>

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  <left out; succeeded>

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
  <left out; succeeded>

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
A disk read error occuredc000000e
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 7629 of name .
An unspecified error occured (6e74667363686b2e b75)
An unspecified error occured (6e74667363686b2e 17b4)
```

The weird thing is, that CrystalDiskInfo shows the device to be healthy. See this screenshot: [can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSoL1.png)

I have just ordered a new SSD to fix the computer, but my question is: is there anything else I can try to get some more life out of this drive? The SSD is a 250GB Samsung 850 Evo, age ~6 years. Who knows more about the error codes? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Strange that the SMART report doesn't show anything wrong... If you rerun chkdsk, does it report the same error at the same location?

Comment: Also strange, that chkdsk reports that the disk has no space to replace bad clusters, while the SMART report show no reallocated sector yet (hence that the spare blocks are still available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have just ordered a new SSD to fix the computer

Good, replace this drive.

> , but my question is: is there anything else I can try to get some
> more life out of this drive? The SSD is a 250GB Samsung 850 Evo, age
> ~6 years.

I would not bother personally. If I'd be tempted, I'd check SMART using for example CrystalDiskInfo and go from there. If you want, add screenshot to your question ^

**Edit:** I do not see much wrongs in the SMART data other than the drive went through a number of error recoveries due to unsafe shutdowns (76 in decimals). You could see this as a sort of 'chkdsk' at the firmware level.

Now corruption is possible due to those, but it seems your issue may have been a purely logical (file system level) one.

What it comes down to is a judgement call whether to continue using the drive or not.

> Who knows more about the error codes? Thanks in advance.

No idea, but IMO kind of moot anyway. This drive is most likely EOL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will replace the drive and toss the old one. Interestingly, CrystalDiskInfo (tried that while isolating the failing component) could find nothing wrong with the drive.

Comment: @c-wizard; can you add screenshot to your post?

Comment: I added the screenshot to the original question.

Comment: Agree, SMART doesn't give much reason for alarm.

Answer (score 1):

Back it up now before it fails and then you cannot recover your data.

Do that first.

Then, if practical, continue to use until the new drive arrives and install the new drive and set it up

There is no practical value (IMHO) to finding out why the old drive failed.  It is going out.

Comment: I got all important files off the PC, fortunately. Unfortunately, Windows crashes within 10 or so minutes, so this SSD will be tossed. Thank you!